# Angular 2 Universal Heroku Deploy

Tags: express, heroku, angular, seo

I have been following the tutorials for implementing an application using Angular 2 universal. On heroku I am getting

```
 at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"
```

and server.ts is

```
// the polyfills must be the first thing imported in node.js
import 'angular2-universal/polyfills';

import * as path from 'path';
import * as express from 'express';
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import * as cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';

// Angular 2
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
// Angular 2 Universal
import { expressEngine } from 'angular2-universal';

// enable prod for faster renders
enableProdMode();

const app = express();
const ROOT = path.join(path.resolve(__dirname, '..'));

// Express View
app.engine('.html', expressEngine);
app.set('views', __dirname);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.use(cookieParser('Angular 2 Universal'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Serve static files
app.use('/assets', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'assets'), {maxAge: 30}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(ROOT, 'dist/client'), {index: false}));


import { serverApi } from './backend/api';
// Our API for demos only
app.get('/data.json', serverApi);

import { ngApp } from './main.node';
// Routes with html5pushstate
// ensure routes match client-side-app
app.get('/', ngApp);
app.get('/about', ngApp);
app.get('/about/*', ngApp);
app.get('/home', ngApp);
app.get('/home/*', ngApp);
app.get('/ourwork', ngApp);
app.get('/ourwork/*', ngApp);
app.get('/services', ngApp);
app.get('/services/*', ngApp);
app.get('/portfolio', ngApp);
app.get('/portfolio/*', ngApp);
app.get('/contact', ngApp);
app.get('/contact/*', ngApp);

// use indexFile over ngApp only when there is too much load on the server
function indexFile(req, res) {
  // when there is too much load on the server just send
  // the index.html without prerendering for client-only
  res.sendFile('/index.html', {root: __dirname});
}

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  var pojo = { status: 404, message: 'No Content' };
  var json = JSON.stringify(pojo, null, 2);
  res.status(404).send(json);
});

// Server
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Listening on: http://localhost:3000');
});
```

I have been looking around and cannot find an answer to this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
// Server
app.listen((process.env.PORT || 3000), () => {
  console.log('Listening on port %d', this.address().port);
});
```

instead of

```
// Server
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Listening on: http://localhost:3000');
});
```

To use the port given by heroku instead of hardcoding 3000.

Comment: Thank you for the response, unfortunately when I added this line of code I began getting the following errors on Heroku. at __webpack_require__ (/app/dist/server/index.js:21:30), at Object.<anonymous> (/app/dist/server/index.js:53:21), at __webpack_require__ (/app/dist/server/index.js:21:30) are you familiar with how I might fix these errors in the Angular 2 Universal starter pack?

Comment: I don't really understand the new errors from you comment. Can you add them to your question?

Comment: Please disregard this comment ^^ I found the solution was that my dev dependencies were different than my prod dependencies. Thank you

Comment: The check shows green on my end is it not showing for you? And yes sir thank you it did help.

Comment: It does, it does, glad I could help!